# Unable to start Google Chrome 78 with selenide

Tags: selenide

I am unable to start Google Chrome Browser Version `78.0.3904.108`.
Version of chromedriver is ChromeDriver `78.0.3904.105`.

```
@Test
public void uiTest() {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/driver/chromedriver");
   System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");

   open("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Error is the following:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}) on port 3782
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;
```

Error is the same even without System.setProperty configurations. Is it possible to be related to Chrome version?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue.
Guava dependency has to be added.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```